Issues While Trying to Create an Internal Testing Release for my Instant App on Google Play Store
I have just created a google instant app with React Native expo. I have generated the aab file and created an internal testing release, which I believe is the same as publishing the app. However, when I try to create a new release that targets instant apps only. I get the errors below.
I get the second error but I do not still understand why I am getting the first one even after creating a release.

Any ideas
I am creating the instant app release like this



"created an internal testing release, which I believe is the same as
publishing the app"

No. Internal testing release is not same as publishing the app. You need to publish the app to the public which will require Google Play's approval. For internal testing, no approval is required

Is there no way to simply create a test release of my instant app?. I don't believe I have to publish it to the store first before I do this

@Tayo
"URL - Launch a URL that matches an intent filter in your app's manifest. When selected, the URL field appears below, where you can enter the URL.
You must fill in this field to launch an Android Instant App. You may also use this to test your Android App Links." https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig

I don't mean testing it locally, I have already done this. I want to test my instant app on play store. basically I want to able to launch a url and have it triggered from play store. How can I do this?

As far as I know, before you can create instant app release, you need to publish standard version of your app to the internal testing/production track
